# @each in Sass does not work when only one element is used

Tags: css

```
In Sass document, @each does not mention only one element.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each

It works well when multiple elements are used as in the example.
under the code I used.
```

`send`

```
@include buttonSelect(
    (
        "album-clear" $button-default-color,
        "album-preview" $button-sub-color,
        "album-add" $button-main-color
    )
);
```

`accept`

```
@mixin buttonSelect($buttons) {

  @each $name, $color in $buttons {
    .#{$name}-button {
      color: $color;
      border-color: $color;
    }
  }
}
```

But, when only one element is used, it expresses the following error.
under, code with error

`send`

```
@include buttonSelect(("inspect-write" $button-main-color));
```

`error`

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: argument `$color` of `rgba($color, $alpha)` must be a color
on line 21 of src/views/scss/mixins/button.scss, in function `rgba`
from line 21 of src/views/scss/mixins/button.scss, in mixin `buttonSelect`
from line 27 of src/views/components/modal/exception/AlbumInspect.scss

> > ```
> >     background-color: rgba($color: $color, $alpha: 1);
> > ```

--------------------------^

why?

Comment: It looks like you are using the buttonSelect mixin with a single button in the list of buttons. When you pass a single button to the mixin, the $buttons variable will contain a tuple (a pair of values) rather than a list of tuples

Comment: i must be use this
("album-add": $button-main-color)

sry